# Custom Web Part Uploading Incorrectly

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts, custom-web-parts

I am trying to upload my custom web part to my sharepoint online site. The upload is successful, but when adding the web part to a site it is not the expected content of the web part. It seems to be an older version of the web part. The web part works as expected when accessing it from the workbench after executing gulp serve.

Expected Result:

[image]

Actual Result:

[image]

Steps I took to upload:

1. In the correct directory I executed gulp package-solution --ship

Result:

[image]

2. I uploaded my sppkg file to the App site with no errors
   [image]
3. I added the web part to one of my sites.

Additional information:

• This web part utilizes the Microsoft Graph API and all API requests are granted

• I transferred computers in the middle of development and just copy + pasted the contents minus the node modules.

• There are no error logs in the google chrome console

Comment: Did you do a bundle as well? "gulp bundle --ship" For good measure, throw in a "gulp clean" first!

Comment: Yes, I did do a "gulp bundle --ship". "gulp clean" managed to fix whatever issue it was having uploading. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Excellent, no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Recapping the comment discussion above with the OP, 
running `gulp clean` before `gulp bundle --ship` and `gulp package-solution --ship` solved this problem.